# Split int into 2 parts in C

Tags: c

Im looking to have the user input a 7 digit Int, which I have already done.

I have an Int value with 7 digits, and I would like to add a hyphen after the 3rd digit (turn it into a phone number format)

The way I want to do this is by having the system create 1 new Int that is equivalent to the first 3 digits of the initial Int, then a second one equivalent to the last 4 digits. Then printf with the hyphen in between

```
int phoneNumber;

scanf

phoneNumber = 1234567
```

---

```
int 1pNum = 123

int 2pNum = 4567

printf(1pNum + "-" + 2pNum)
```

Don't worry, I know the format in which i explained that would not work exactly, I just want to know how to split it

Comment: `1pNum = phoneNumber / 10000; 2pNum = phoneNumber % 10000;` ?

Comment: there's no need to split it into two ints, you can just store it in a string and print two halfs of that.

Comment: `2pNum = phoneNumber % 10000; 1pNum = (phoneNumber - 2pNum) / 10000;`  Something like this will do it.

Comment: Kamil Cuk has a good idea tho lol

Comment: Phone numbers are more string than number-is there a specific reason you need them in a numeric type?

Comment: `1pNum` and `2pNum` are not valid identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int phoneNumber = 1234567;
  int p1 = phoneNumber / 10000;
  int p2 = phoneNumber % 10000;
  printf("OK: %03d-%04d\n", p1, p2);
  // OK: 123-4567
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This probably won't do what you want when 0s happen in the wrong place. For example, 1230056 will print "123-56". You can fix this with "%03d-%04d".

Answer (score 0):

A clean code for this problem would be to convert it to string and insert hyphen in 4th character. Assuming you are using c:
first part is from int to string you can use code like (http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/)

```
 template <typename T>
   string NumberToString ( T Number )
 {
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << Number;
    return ss.str();
 }
```

and for second part you can use .insert like:

```
strNumber.insert(4, "-");
```

Comment: The question is tagged `C`, not `C++`.

Comment: Correct Thanks for letting me know Ajay, they are close and the concept would be same and helpful for Owen :) I will try to find exact code for C as well and Post here